# Remove parent categories if a child category has been assigned to a post

Tags: php, wordpress

Some of my posts have categories assigned as follows:

```
- Adverts
-- Agriculture and Gardening
--- Agricultural tools
```

What I want is to remove all the parent categories (ancestors) from the post, leaving only the child categories, targeting only those that have 'Adverts' as their top ancestor. I can do this without problems from the admin by unchecking parent categories and re-saving the post, but I can't do it with a code / programmatically.

I tried the below code (in functions.php) using a clean Twenty Seventeen child theme and with all plugins disabled, in the latest version of WP by saving a post in admin with all the above mentioned categories checked. Analyzing the output of `error_log()` (see in code) it seems everything is OK, if I interpret things correctly, but when I look at the post on admin or frontend, the parent categories are still there. What am I doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'remove_ancestor_terms' );
function remove_ancestor_terms( $post_id ) {
    // check if it's a post revision or an autosave
    if( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // targeted top category ancestor
    $ancestor_slug = 'adverts';
    $ancestor_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $ancestor_slug, 'category' );
    $ancestor_id   = $ancestor_term ? $ancestor_term->term_id : false;

    // get the post terms
    $post_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

    // this is a copy of $post_terms
    $keep_terms = $post_terms;

    // check each term for ancestors
    foreach( $post_terms as $term_id ) {
        $term_ancestors = get_ancestors( $term_id, 'category' );

        // skip terms with no ancestors or if they do not have the targeted ancestor
        if( empty( $term_ancestors ) || ! in_array( $ancestor_id, $term_ancestors ) ) { continue; }

        // remove ancestors from $keep_terms, keep only the last child
        $keep_terms = array_diff( $keep_terms, $term_ancestors );
    }

    /* error_log( 'before: ' . print_r( wp_get_post_categories( $post_id, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ), true ) );

    this is outputted by error_log():
    Array
    (
        [0] => 83 // Adverts
        [1] => 125 // Agricultural tools
        [2] => 100 // Agriculture and Gardening
    )
    */

    // replace post categories
    $return = wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $keep_terms );

    /*error_log(  'return: ' . print_r( $return, true ) );

    this is outputted by error_log():
    Array
    (
        [0] => 125 // Agricultural tools
    )
    */

    /*error_log( 'after: ' . print_r( wp_get_post_categories( $post_id, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ), true ) );

    this is outputted by error_log():
    Array
    (
        [0] => 125 // Agricultural tools
    )
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_parent_category($post_id) {
    $categories = get_the_category($post_id);

    $child_category_ids = array();

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category->parent != 0) {
            $child_category_ids[] = $category->term_id;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($child_category_ids)) {
        $parent_categories = get_categories(array(
            'child_of' => $child_category_ids,
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));

        foreach ($parent_categories as $parent_category) {
            wp_remove_object_terms($post_id, $parent_category->term_id, 'category');
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'remove_parent_category');
```